# Aligning checkboxes with labels in the center

Tags: checkbox, alignment, center

anyone else encounter this annoying issue?

Whenever it comes to checkboxes, I always run into alignment issues. This is my most recent one. I can't seem to get the checkboxes with their labels to align to the center properly.

Any tips on how to do so would be hugely appreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>
            Checkbox
        </title>
    
        <style type="text/css">
    
        .checkbox-grid div {
            width:25%;
        }
        
        .checkbox-grid {
        
        width:50%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
          
          .center {
              display:flex;
              justify-content:center;
              flex-wrap:wrap;
    
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       



    .checkbox-grid div {
        width:25%;
    }
    
    .checkbox-grid {
    
    width:50%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
      
      .center {
          display:flex;
          justify-content:center;
          flex-wrap:wrap;

      }
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Checkbox
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="checkbox-grid">
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="value1" /><label for="text1">Text 1</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text2" value="value2" /><label for="text2">Text 2</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text3" value="value3" /><label for="text3">Text 3</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text4" value="value4" /><label for="text4">Text 4</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="value5" /><label for="text5">Text 5</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text6" value="value6" /><label for="text6">Text 6</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text7" value="value7" /><label for="text7">Text 7</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="text8" value="value8" /><label for="text8">Text 8</label></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            hello
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Stack told me my post is too much code and not enough of an explanation, but I think it's pretty self explanatory, so I'm just writing some waffle at the bottom, don't mind me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
.checkbox-grid{ display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; }
```